# How to localize ASP.Net Memebership provider in WPF application

Tags: asp.net, wpf, localization, membership, provider

We are using ASP.Net Membership provider for user management module in our WPF based application. It seems to be working fine. But now we want to localize our WPF application, and don't know how to do that with respect to the data stored as part of Membership Provider. Is Localization supported by Membership Provider ? Is so, any input on this would be of great help.

Regards,
Smitha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what sort of data do you store in with the provider that needs to be localized and how you tie it to the UI.

For pre-determined values you can use resources, and then pull out the required string from a resource.

For user-generated stuff (such as usernames and other stuff like that) I don't think you want to localize that.

Comment: We had localized the UI controls and user messages using resources.  UserName and Password, we need not localize..But Roles in ASP.Net Membership provider needs to be lozalized. Definately user would like to see Role like 'Admin', 'Guest' in localized language than in english... But I dont know how to achieve the same ...any idea on this would be of great help.....

Comment: Idea: Add a string to the resource with the role's name in English as its key. When displaying the role name, use the resource with the role name as the key.